# How to POS encoded as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hi can someone guide me how to POST a URL encoded encoded as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Actually the API suggestion complete is below, Note: i have all variables which needs to be POST in url. I just cannot figure out the way how to post it correctly Thanks in advance.

After the user has logged in and given their permission, the Envato API will redirect them back to your application on the Confirmation URL provided, with a single-use authentication code provided in the query string (eg. http://your.app/callback?code=abc123...). You must use this code to request an access token from the API, by sending the following POST request from your server (encoded as application/x-www-form-urlencoded), replacing [CODE] with the code you've just received, [CLIENT_SECRET] with your secret application key, and the other fields as necessary:

```
POST https://api.envato.com/token
     grant_type=authorization_code&
     code=[CODE]&
     client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&
     client_secret=[CLIENT_SECRET]
```

The server will respond with an access token:

```
{
  "refresh_token": "GBdxWsxo1CqAK9yCneH75wgkXw1q7bio",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "access_token": "c0lQ2WLYW9qAZ9RH12cH1fJPzVWSscXP",
  "expires_in": 3600
}
```

So how would we post the URL and get the required response. Thanks.

Comment: _“encoded as application/x-www-form-urlencoded”_ means nothing more than what you’re seeing in the example already - name=value pairs, separated by an ampersand. In PHP you can use http_build_query to create such a string form a given array of keys and values. (And how to make a basic POST request is something you can easily research yourself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to extract the query params of your callback:

```
let params = {}; location.search.substring(1).split('&').forEach(v => { params[v.split('=')[0]] = decodeURI(v.split('=')[1]);}) ;
```

Then, use your favorite api to make an ajax call and just do:

```
let client_id = 'your_awesome_client_id_param';
let client_secret = 'your_amazing_client_secret_param';
fetch('https://api.envato.com/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: `grant_type=authorization_code&code=${params.code}&client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${clientSecret}`
})
.then(r => return r.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: Thank you! however i achieved it in a different way but your answer was great to get the right directions! have great day.